# Quartus 10166 error: "Always_comb construct does not infer purely combinational logic"

Tags: system-verilog, rtl

The error is coming from the second always construct. I have no idea how a latch is inferred since I've specified the output for every possible input state. Any ideas?

```
  module statemachine(input slow_clock, input resetb,
                        input [3:0] dscore, input [3:0] pscore, input [3:0] pcard3,
                        output logic load_pcard1, output logic load_pcard2,output logic load_pcard3,
                        output logic load_dcard1, output logic load_dcard2, output logic load_dcard3,
                        output logic player_win_light, output logic dealer_win_light);

    enum logic[2:0] {Start = 3'b000, FirstP = 3'b001, FirstD = 3'b010, SecondP = 3'b011, SecondD = 3'b100, ThirdP = 3'b101, ThirdD =  3'b110, GameOver = 3'b111} state, next_state;

    always_comb
    begin
      case(state)
        Start: next_state = FirstP; 
        FirstP: next_state = FirstD;
        FirstD: next_state = SecondP;
        SecondP: next_state = SecondD;
        SecondD: next_state = pscore == 4'b1000 || pscore == 4'b1001 || dscore == 4'b1000 || dscore == 4'b1001 ? GameOver :
                   pscore <= 4'b0101 ? ThirdP :
                 dscore <= 4'b0101 ? ThirdD : GameOver;             
        ThirdP: next_state = dscore == 4'b0111 ? GameOver : 
                 dscore == 4'b0110 && (pcard3 == 4'b0110 || pcard3 == 4'b0111) ? ThirdD :
                       dscore == 4'b0101 && (pcard3 == 4'b0100 || pcard3 == 4'b0101 || pcard3 == 4'b0110 || pcard3 == 4'b0111) ? ThirdD :
                 dscore == 4'b0100 && (pcard3 != 4'b0 && pcard3 != 4'b0001 && pcard3 != 4'b1000) ? ThirdD :
                   dscore == 4'b0011 && pcard3 != 4'b1000 ? ThirdD :
                     GameOver;  
        ThirdD: next_state = GameOver;
        GameOver: next_state = GameOver;
       endcase
    end

    always_ff @ (posedge slow_clock) begin
        if (resetb == 0)
          state <= Start;
        else
          state <= next_state;
       end

    always_comb
    begin
      case(state)
        Start: 
        begin
          load_pcard1 = 0;
            load_dcard1 = 0;
            load_pcard2 = 0;
            load_dcard2 = 0;
            load_pcard3 = 0;
            load_dcard3 = 0;
            player_win_light = 0;
            dealer_win_light = 0;
        end
        FirstP:
        begin 
            load_pcard1 = 1;
            load_dcard1 = 0;
            load_pcard2 = 0;
            load_dcard2 = 0;
            load_pcard3 = 0;
            load_dcard3 = 0;
            player_win_light = 0;
            dealer_win_light = 0;   
        end 
        FirstD: 
          begin load_dcard1 = 1;
          load_pcard1 = 0;
            load_pcard2 = 0;
            load_dcard2 = 0;
            load_pcard3 = 0;
            load_dcard3 = 0;
            player_win_light = 0;
            dealer_win_light = 0;
          end   
        SecondP: 
          begin
            load_pcard1 = 0;
            load_dcard1 = 0;
          load_pcard2 = 1;
            load_dcard2 = 0;
            load_pcard3 = 0;
            load_dcard3 = 0;
            player_win_light = 0;
            dealer_win_light = 0;
          end
        SecondD:
          begin
            load_pcard1 = 0;
            load_dcard1 = 0;
          load_pcard2 = 0;
            load_dcard2 = 1;
            load_pcard3 = 0;
            load_dcard3 = 0;
            player_win_light = 0;
            dealer_win_light = 0;
          end

        ThirdP:  
         begin
            load_pcard1 = 0;
            load_dcard1 = 0;
          load_pcard2 = 0;
            load_dcard2 = 0;
            load_pcard3 = 1;
            load_dcard3 = 0;
            player_win_light = 0;
            dealer_win_light = 0;
          end
        ThirdD:
         begin
            load_pcard1 = 0;
            load_dcard1 = 0;
          load_pcard2 = 0;
            load_dcard2 = 0;
            load_pcard3 = 0;
            load_dcard3 = 1;
            player_win_light = 0;
            dealer_win_light = 0;
          end
        GameOver:
          begin
            load_pcard1 = 0;
            load_dcard1 = 0;
          load_pcard2 = 0;
            load_dcard2 = 0;        
          load_dcard3 = 0;
            load_dcard3 = 0;
             player_win_light = pscore > dscore ? 1 : dscore > pscore ? 0 : 0;
            dealer_win_light = dscore > pscore ? 1 : pscore > dscore ? 0 : 0;  
          end
        default:
        begin
          load_pcard1 = 0;
            load_dcard1 = 0;
            load_pcard2 = 0;
            load_dcard2 = 0;
            load_pcard3 = 0;
            load_dcard3 = 0;
            player_win_light = 0;
            dealer_win_light = 0;
        end

      endcase

    end

    endmodule
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a typo. In the GameOver state, you have `load_dcard3 = 0` twice and don't assign to `load_pcard3`.

Comment: Re: question edits. You're quite right that the error message text should be preserved. My fault, I hadn't read it properly. Beyond that, English is dead clear: I imply, you infer. Here, Verilog implies and Quartus infers. Some firmware engineers use them interchangeably but they're as distinct as 'get' and 'put'. Crud software engineer(s) at Altera. Good answer, upvoted.

Comment: I'm trying to transfer my Quartus compilation onto the De1-Soc board, and the process is failing. I've selected the correct device (Cyclone V and its sub-model), and the USB blaster is showing up when connected to the device. However the transfer 'fails'. This may be a stretch, but any ideas ?https://imgur.com/a/aiEt6BN

Comment: @GauiX3 - You should ask a new question with the details. I doubt I will be able to answer it though.